# Error in Raiserror After upgrading SqlServer 2008 R2 to 2017

Tags: sql-server

Please advise and share your solution.

**In 2008 R2**

```
DECLARE @ErrMsg varchar (25) 
SET @ErrMsg = 'Test Raiserror in 2008 R2'
RAISERROR 50002 @ErrMsg
```

The above statement produces the following output.

> Msg 50002, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Test Raiserror in 2008 R2 Completion time: 2022-03-12T20:12:20.1296499+03:00

**In 2017**

```
DECLARE @ErrMsg varchar (25) 
SET @ErrMsg = 'Test Raiserror in 2017'
RAISERROR 50002 @ErrMsg
```

The above statement produces the following output.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near '50002'. Completion time: 2022-03-12T20:13:24.4256066+03:00

Comment: The syntax has changed. In fact, you were relying on undocumented functionality from versions before 2000. Suggest you review the documentation for all the syntax, functionality, removal, and deprecation changes that have occurred in the last decade.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, that syntax changed. Tried Throw is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RAISERROR 50002 @ErrMsg
```

This form of `RAISERROR` syntax was deprecated many versions ago and removed from the product entirely in the SQL Server 2012 release. From the [Discontinued Database Engine Functionality in SQL Server 2012 page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms144262(v=sql.110)):

> Discontinued feature: RAISERROR in the format RAISERROR integer
> 'string' is discontinued.
>
> Replacement: Rewrite the statement using the current RAISERROR(…)
> syntax.

As an alternative to the [current RAISERROR syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), you could instead use [THROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as below. This allows use of the same same user-defined error number  without having to add message to sys.messages (which `RAISERROR` requires). Be sure to terminate the preceding statement with a semi-colon.

```
THROW 50002, @ErrMsg, 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. Throw is working.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a comma between the parameters of your `RAISERROR` call in `RAISERROR 50002 @ErrMsg`. It should actually be `RAISERROR 50002, @ErrMsg` to be syntactically correct.

Per the docs on [`RAISERROR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
RAISERROR msg_id, msg_str
```

Also please note that `RAISERROR` is a little bit deprecated in itself, as the docs caution:

> The RAISERROR statement does not honor SET XACT_ABORT. New applications should use THROW instead of RAISERROR.

As recommended you should generally use the [`THROW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) keyword instead, e.g:

```
DECLARE @ErrMsg varchar (25) 
SET @ErrMsg = 'Test Raiserror in 2008 R2'
;THROW 50002, @ErrMsg, 0;
```

*Note the required preceding semicolon before the `THROW` keyword. Though you should generally terminate all statements with a semicolon anyway.*

Comment: Thank for your valuable solutions. Finally THROW 50002, @ErrMsg, 1; is working.

Comment: @jvlove No problem! Best of luck!